# Eclipse m2eclipse clean, build projects, build automatically commands, what are they?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

What is the command that m2eclipse runs when you

highlight a project -> Menu Project -> Clean -> Select anything -> Ok ?

It then goes on to "Building Workspace".

What is the command that allows it to do so?

The reason I am asking is that I am trying to do this from outside Eclipse, from the command line. I am trying to automate all maven stuff in a Groovy script. I am on Windows xp.

**EDIT:**
Also, the command update maven dependencies would be nice to have as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You 'are doing it outside Eclipse'. Do you want to update the dependencies for your eclipse project (so eclipse can work with the project again)? Then try mvn eclipse:eclipse to update maven dependencies.

Comment: @proko. He's working with m2e. For these projects you no longer need mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: holy cow! you think i can run :

mvn clean install -DskipTests=true eclipse:eclipse 

or do you think the eclipse stuff have to be run separately ?

Comment: @alexander that is assuming m2e works as it should, which it doesnt

Comment: Does this output look correct btw: 

[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [eclipse:eclipse {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Not running eclipse plugin goal for pom project
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER

Answer (score 1):

Maven-invocations are put in the Run and Debug menus.  Just building the workspace does not run maven - it just does all the work Eclipse needs to do to know your files.

Comment: That is not what I was asking for. I am asking what the command or commands are run when you do build workspace.

Comment: Not sure about that... if you look at the Maven console (in Eclipse) you can see Maven chugging away in the background when you build your m2eclipse project. Not sure about m2e, though.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes these will suffice for the command line build:

```
cd /to/where/pom.xml/is
mvn clean
mvn install
```

Comment: yeah, i already do that mvn clean install... perhaps that is enough

Answer (score 0):

No commands are directly run.  Instead, the m2e plugin uses the configuration in the pom to create equivalent configurations in eclipse.

For example, if you change the source directories it will update the eclipse source directories for the java builder.  If you change the target directories for the source compilation, it'll ensure that when you do a Project -> Clean, the plugin knows which directories to clean.

If you are trying to do this though a scripting language, I would recommend just running commands on the command line.  The alternative would be to add the maven libraries to the classpath and to use them.